# PostgreSQL count of records by status

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

In my PostgreSQL database I have `users` table which has the following columns:

```
id - integer
email - string
blocked - boolean
```

Now I want to have sql query that returns me following results:

```
total:                blocked:                unblocked
total count of users  count of blocked users  count of users that are not blocked
```

How can I do that in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count()` with [filter:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

```
select
    count(*) as total,
    count(*) filter (where blocked) as blocked,
    count(*) filter (where not blocked) as unblocked
from users
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS USER_RC
     , SUM(CASE WHEN BLOCKED=TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BLOCKED_RC
     , SUM(CASE WHEN BLOCKED=TRUE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS UNBLOCKED_RC  
FROM TX1;
```

or if you prefer (it uses only two aggregation functions):

```
SELECT A.*, USER_RC-BLOCKED_RC AS UNBLOCKED_RC
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS USER_RC, SUM(CASE WHEN BLOCKED=TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BLOCKED_RC 
     FROM TX1) A
;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO TX1 VALUES (1,'aaa',FALSE);
INSERT INTO TX1 VALUES (2,'bbb',TRUE);
INSERT INTO TX1 VALUES (3,'ccc',TRUE);
INSERT INTO TX1 VALUES (4,'ddd',TRUE);
INSERT INTO TX1 VALUES (5,'eee',FALSE);
```

Output:

```
user_rc blocked_rc  unblocked_rc
    5       3           2
```